# Adding aggregate over filtered self-join field to Admin list_display

Tags: django, django-admin, django-orm

I would like to augment one of my model admins with an interesting value. Given a model like this:

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    pass

class Registration(models.Model):
    participant = models.ForeignKey(Participant)
    is_going = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Is going')
```

Now, I would like to show the number of other `Registration`s for this `Participant` where `is_going` is `False`. So, something akin to this SQL query:

```
SELECT reg.*, COUNT(past.id) AS not_going_num
FROM   registrations AS reg, registrations AS past
WHERE  past.participant_id = reg.participant_id AND
       past.is_going = False
```

I think I can extend the `Admin`'s `queryset()` method according to [Django Admin, Show Aggregate Values From Related Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276509/django-admin-show-aggregate-values-from-related-model), by annotating it with the extra `Count`, but I still cannot figure out how to work the self-join and filter into this.

I looked at [Self join with django ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578362/self-join-with-django-orm) and [Django self join , How to convert this query to ORM query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653360/django-self-join-how-to-convert-this-query-to-orm-query), but the former is doing `SELECT *` AND the latter seems to have data model problems.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Not sure how I can use SQL to extend the ModelAdmin's queryset.

Comment: Once the custom SQL  runs, it's a common queryset https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/

Comment: Yes, but I don't think you can add raw SQL to an existing queryset, and so I would have to replace the entire queryset SQL, which seems tricky and prone to failure if I ever want to upgrade Django.

Comment: ORM has it's limits though, there is so much you can effectively do  with object oriented framework with sets operations.

Comment: Do you know what I want is impossible, or do you not know how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

See edit history for previous version of the answer.

The admin implementation below will display "Not Going Count" for each `Registration` model. The "Not Going Count" is the count of `is_going=False` for the registration's `participant`.

```
@admin.register(Registration)
class RegistrationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ['id', 'participant', 'is_going', 'ng_count']

    def ng_count(self, obj):
        return obj.not_going_count
    ng_count.short_description = 'Not Going Count'

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(RegistrationAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.filter(participant__registration__isnull=False)
        qs = qs.annotate(not_going_count=Sum(
            Case(
                When(participant__registration__is_going=False, then=1),
                default=0,
                output_field=models.IntegerField())
            ))
        return qs
```

---

Below is a more thorough explanation of the QuerySet:

```
qs = qs.filter(participant__registration__isnull=False)
```

The filter causes Django to perform two joins - an `INNER JOIN` to participant table, and a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to registration table.

```
qs = qs.annotate(not_going_count=Sum(
    Case(
        When(participant__registration__is_going=False, then=1),
        default=0,
        output_field=models.IntegerField())
    )    
))
```

This is a standard aggregate, which will be used to `SUM` up the count of `is_going=False`. This translates into the SQL

```
SUM(CASE WHEN past."is_going" = False THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

The sum is generated for each registration model, and the sum belongs to the registration's participant.

Comment: Thank you, this is moving in the right direction! So how could I add this to the `queryset()` for a `ModelAdmin`?

Comment: I've added an example for adding the query to the admin, and displaying the count on the admin model list page.

Comment: Deleted comment, since it was wrong (had incorrectly translated your code to my models, which are slightly different). I now have something working, but it seems to duplicate the rows by the number of registrations, so it appears like the aggregate isn't working right yet.

Comment: Hmm, in your question you asked for "number of other registrations for the participant where `is_going=False`" - the values you see should be exactly that. There should be duplications because "not going count" is specific to a participant, not a registration. The registration admin displays each model on its own row, but the same participant can appear on multiple rows. Maybe you can elaborate a bit more what you think is not right?

Comment: I want the admin to show a list of `Registration`s, but show the `not_going_count` for the `Participant` that is linked from the `Registration`. (Note that `Registration`s are linked to `Participant`s, but not the other way around!) Sorry if this was not clear before!

Comment: The `not_going_count` should already be for the participant that is linked to the registration. I took a screenshot of my own admin - http://i.imgur.com/DV5Cqzc.png - the "Not Going Count" is specific to the participant, and it should work for the example in your question. Would you by any chance have other filters in your own code that may be changing the query?

Comment: So, yes, I'm also applying filters on other aspects of the `Registration`, and I guess it's these that no longer correctly apply when I add your code? (E.g., think about `Registration` having a `year` field, and filtering on that.)

Comment: Wow, I think it's working. For now, I've left out the `qs.filter(participant__registration__isnull=False)` clause, because my `Participant`s don't have a `registration` field, so I don't think that makes sense. I'm still unclear how/why your code actually results in the required self-join, but I guess there's no arguing with results...

Comment: If still have questions or need more assistance with this, feel free to send an email to me which can be found on https://github.com/derekkwok

Answer (score 0):

I might misunderstood, but you can do for single participant:

```
participant = Participant.objects.get(id=1)
not_going_count = Registration.objects.filter(participant=participant,
                                              is_going=False).count()
```

For all participants,

```
from django.db.models import Count
Registration.objects.filter(is_going=False).values('participant') \
                                           .annotate(not_going_num=Count('participant'))
```

Django doc about [aggregating for each item in a queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset).

Comment: That looks simple, but doesn't solve the issue of doing this as part of a QuerySet against the Registration object already (that is, doing it for a larger number of Participants at once, not just one).

Comment: Here you're filtering the wrong side: my `is_going=False` is on `past`, not on `reg`.

Comment: May I ask why do you do self join? Do you have fields that refer to the same model?

Comment: That is how the domain works. For a given Registration, I want to see how many times a Participant canceled on Registrations in the past.

Comment: Maybe Registration.objects.get(participant=this_participant).registrations_set(is_going=False)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to understand the way you find out whether a registration happens in the past. Maybe somebody else could help.

Comment: So "in the past" doesn't really matter. For now I'm basically looking at all registrations that are not the current registration.

Comment: Aviah: that still doesn't tell me how I can bring this all into a single QuerySet.