# Self-referential aggregation in django

Tags: django, django-models

Is it possible to write a self-referential aggregation in django?

For example, given the following model definition:

```
from django.db import models

class Match(models.Model):
    match_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    league = models.ForeignKey(League, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete.models.CASCADE)
```

I would like to annotate each `Match` object with the number of prior matches.  (And ultimately with other conditions, e.g., prior matches with a given team playing.)

My initial thought was something like:

```
from django.db.models import Q, F, Count

matches = Match.objects.filter(team__name='xyz')

matches.annotate(
    prior_matches=Count('match_id', filter=(
        Q(start_time__lt=F('start_time')
    ))
)
```

Unfortunately, this seems to give `prior_matches=0` for all objects.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325643/adding-aggregate-over-filtered-self-join-field-to-admin-list-display) suggests following a foreign key and using the reverse relationship, but that seems clumsy, and it's also got two problems:

1. It's not strictly equivalent.  For example, the following snippet works, but will do a count of prior matches within a given league rather than overall.  I guess you could hack around this by creating a placeholder model which all `Match` objects have as a foreign key, but that doesn't seem ideal.

```
matches.annotate(
     prior_matches=Sum(Case(
         When(start_time__lt=F('league__matches__start_time'), then=1),
         default=0,
         output_field=models.IntegerField()
     ))
)
```

2. The provided count is relative to all prior matches in the database, not just those in the filtered queryset.  For example, the above code finds counts of all prior matches, even though the `matches` queryset was filtered for a specific team.  I can't think of a good way around this (save for repeating the full filter conditions applied to the queryset in each `Q` / `filter` clause, which isn't generalisable in a manager).

---

As a motivation / to avoid an xy problem, one of the snippets of (pseudo)code that I'm looking to replace by working at the database level is the following:

```
def generate_stats(match):
    matches = Match.objects.filter(start_time__lt=match.start_time)

    for team in (match.home_team, match.away_team):
        q_involving = Q(home_team=team) | Q(away_team=team)
        team_matches = matches.filter(q_involving)

        team_matches.aggregate(...)  # get stats
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your first code to

```
from django.db import models

class Match(models.Model):
    match_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    league = models.ForeignKey(League, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete.models.CASCADE)
```

Else, it might be that you haven't actually added a "Match"

Comment: Unfortunately the model definition isn't the issue, and the data exists.  (There's no need to do primary keys as AutoFields, especially if connecting to external data sources.)